# Do we really need to delete the home directory when we give up with encryption?

Tags: home-directory, ecryptfs

There are several threads concerning deactivating encryption by **ecryptfs** on a home directory. A selection is listed below. All (seem to) suggest that the current home directory will be wiped out by the process of removing encryption.

The output of `ecryptfs-setup-private --undo` says

> In the event that you want to remove your eCryptfs Private Directory setup,
>   you will need to very carefully perform the following actions manually:
>
> 1. Obtain your Private directory mountpoint
>      $ PRIVATE=`cat ~/.ecryptfs/Private.mnt 2>/dev/null || echo $HOME/Private`
> 2. Ensure that you have moved all relevant data out of your `$PRIVATE` directory
> 3. Unmount your encrypted private directory
>      `$ ecryptfs-umount-private`
> 4. Make your Private directory writable again
>      `$ chmod 700 $PRIVATE`
> 5. Remove $PRIVATE, ~/.Private, ~/.ecryptfs
>      Note: THIS IS VERY PERMANENT, BE VERY CAREFUL
>      `$ rm -rf $PRIVATE ~/.Private ~/.ecryptfs`
> 6. Uninstall the utilities (this is specific to your Linux distribution)
>      `$ sudo apt-get remove ecryptfs-utils libecryptfs0`

Since `$PRIVATE` is actually  `/home/user` (the directory protected by encryption, please check), the current home directory gets emptied and deleted because of one's own doing through `rm -rf $PRIVATE`

I noticed one fellow's interesting remark on line 5. Reportedly https://askubuntu.com/a/10049/446253 did not find deleting home necessary, which is a very interesting hint. Making back-ups of data is good in its own right, but it's no immaterial thing if you could remove encryption without manipulating your user home content!

I am not certainly asking to put your own data at risk in place of mine, but could more experienced people *judge* whether a step 5 like `rm -rf  ~/.Private ~/.ecryptfs` would be sufficient instead?

This could help out people who struggle with full disks to be emptied and cannot resort to network file systems because of encryption, for example.

### Sources

[How to stop using built-in home directory encryption?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/)

[Can you unencrypt / remove encryption from a user home folder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107410)

[How to disable encrypted home directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138950)

[Can I disable full-disk encryption?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245112)

[Removing Encryption on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/706056)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took courage and created an encrypted mock user, say *unlockMe* (owing no sudo rights). On the terminal I did the following:

1. log in as user *unlockMe*
2. `$ ecryptfs-umount-private  ## as per instructions no. 3`
3. `$ chmod 700 .  ## as per instructions no. 4; . is \home\unlockMe`
4. `$ rm -rf ~/.Private ~/.ecryptfs  ## unlike the instructions no. 5`
5. exit the *unlockMe* profile
6. log in as another user
7. `$ sudo ls /home/unlockMe` whence I could see the unencrypted content. In contrast, in case of encrypted content, I would have rather seen the files `Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop` and `README.txt`

Also note that one does not need to uninstall the utilities (unlike instructions no. 6) -- obviously not, if other users keep on using encryption.

Tested with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and package ecryptfs-utils version 104-0ubuntu1.14.04.4.

Out of this single experiment I would conclude that there is no need to move your data anywhere else to give up encryption.

One reserve that I still have is that these operations might not actually mean giving up encryption completely, rather making the folders visible, (breaking the outer shell, so to speak). The directory `/home/.encryptfs/unlockMe` still seems to be storing a lot of information in encrypted form. So it might well be that there much more going under the surface, and I await expert answers here.

Please feel free to comment, edit or post alternative answers.