# Expanding an encrypted LVM partition question

Tags: partitioning, 18.04, encryption, ssd, lvm

This is absolutely not a previously answered question!  I have spent weeks (literally) reading these posts and documentation and for the most part the information and answers have been vague, misleading, downright incorrect or so convoluted that no normal person could ever follow them.  Based on the number of comments by users who also had problems following these "answers" what's really needed is a clear, simple, flawless FAQ type procedure.  It just shouldn't be this hard to resize a system when you install a larger SSD!

I'd prefer to do this via command lines but the several CLI answers I've seen posted have not worked.  And one answer included the statement "say a prayer" after you enter this command.  Like that's a procedure I want to follow.

The solution that looked the most promising involved kvpm but there is no information I can find that easily explains how to perform this simple task.

The procedure that came closest to success is posted at [Encrypted drive cloning - resizing partitions problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110790/encrypted-drive-cloning-expanding-partitions-problem)

I'm very wearing reading poorly prepared documentation, answers that were obviously never tested before they were posted and trying various advice and commands that ultimately turn out to not work.

This is a VERY simple question:

I have a 100% running 18.04.2 Ubuntu installation that I've cloned onto a much larger 500 GB SDD.  Everything works great but since I cloned it using dd the new SDD has a partition size of 32 GB (the size of the old SSD).

What we users need is a clear, correct, mistake-free, bullet-proof procedure for expanding the encrypted LVM partition (LUKS and ubuntu-vg) to use the available 485 gig of currently unallocated space.  This ought not be rocket science and could probably be accomplished in a half dozen to a dozen commands, right?

Flames and downvotes are not going to be helpful here.  An answer that works for everyone searching for a solution to this issue will help a lot of folks visiting here not just me.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You have the need for it, so test & then write the documentation yourself, write it here (or better in my opinion on wiki.ubuntu.com).  If you don't have another system to test (before using production data), clone your partition to some of the free space & expand that.

Comment: I count five paragraphs with various rants or complaints about the AskUbuntu community in them, including the entire first paragraph. Are you sure that's how you want to attract knowledgeable folks to answer the question?

Comment: It's not a rant and the snarky comment above yours demonstrates why I felt I needed to preface my question thusly.  This isn't just for me.  This issue (partition resizing) comes up frequently and everything I've read just adds to the confusion.  The wiki page on this topic is badly in need of a cleanup and updating.  I don't mean to be offensive but neither do I care to be flamed for asking a legitimate question that many people here have also struggled with.  I am not at all novice with *NIX.  It just doesn't need to be this difficult to expand encrypted/LVM filesystems.