# how do you disable the boot password?

Tags: 16.04

when installing 16.04 I must have checked an option that added a password at boot and at login.  I don't really want to password at boot just the log in password.  how do I disable it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I disable full-disk encryption?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/245112/can-i-disable-full-disk-encryption)

Answer (score 3):

From your description you opted for full disk encryption.

Unless you are a total Linux guru, you'll just have to re-install Ubuntu.

Even for a Linux guru it would be a pain in the neck.

---

## UPDATE:

Here's a workaround from @Alcuin in the comments:

> Just set your user account to auto-login. That way you still only have
> to enter one password at startup while keeping your disk fully
> encrypted.

---

> If Ubuntu asks for an encryption passphrase during boot (i.e. on the
> text console before the login screen is displayed), this indicates
> that a full disk encryption method was used. (There's more than one
> way to do this, but I'll keep the answer general.) The encryption is
> handled by an extra software layer between the file system and the
> physical hard drive, not the file system itself.
>
> There is no simple method or tool to undo this. With some knowledge
> about how Linux systems work, it can be done. You'd have to move the
> whole file system (or all files) to another partition (with enough
> free space) or external HDD. Then, remove the encrypted container, and
> recreate the file system without encryption. Finally, make sure that
> the new file system is properly recognized by the boot loader and
> mount -a before rebooting.
>
> If possible, it's best to avoid this time consuming and error-prone
> procedure. **Just do a fresh install. For a new users, this is the
> quickest and safest option.**

The above quote was taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/245159/518562).

Comment: Intsead of re-installing, just set your user account to auto-login. That way you still only have to enter one password at startup while keeping your disk fully encrypted.