# Remove encryption (decrypt) root partition ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: partitioning, encryption

I have recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Laptop and choose to encrypt the root and swap partitions (there are other two windows partitions not encrypted). They encrypt type is plain (no LUK). Could anybody tell me whether it is possible to decrypt the linux partition without format the harddisk? I have the pass-phrase at hand.

Sorry it seems a duplicated question but I can not get a clear answer somewhere about this problem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: In order to boot it has to be decrypted so perhaps it's better you explain what the goal is by decrypting it without actually booting the system.

Comment: The system is booting normally. I just want to get rid of the encryption. I tried to install Ubuntu again from usb but it is still encrypted after installing even I deleted the ext4 and swap partition and made new ones. Now they both encrypted (plain method).

Comment: I may have misunderstood due to an unorthodox terminology - decrypting and getting rid of encryption are not the same thing - but what you're saying now makes no sense. When installing the user **decides** whether or not to use encryption, the installer won't encrypt unless told to do so.

Comment: As I already chose to encrypt the partition, is there any way to revert this action?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/245159/589808