# BusyBox shell on reboot, missing file alert

Tags: 16.04, reboot, busybox

Upon reboot I am sent to a BusyBox shell with an error message:

```
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/66301ae5-dd52-4e24-8345-e216cba1d1ea does not exist.
```

Perhaps relevant:

- I did recently format a large data storage drive on my machine, but
  it was not where system files are stored.
- My harddrive was encrypted.

Any advice about what is happening and what I could do to fix it?

Comment: Boot a live usb and decrypt your install. Check your partitions and see if you need to edit /etc/fstab

Comment: Decrypting my install didn't seem trivial: https://askubuntu.com/questions/245112/can-i-disable-full-disk-encryption
Thus I had to reinstall :(