# Can you remove the encryption of a drive?

Tags: encryption

When I installed Ubuntu I encrypted the drive mostly out of curiosity and because someone told me to do it, but now it is more of a hustle than anything.

Is there a way to remove encryption or am I stuck with it?

Answer (score 1):

See Jan's answer: [Can I disable full-disk encryption?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245112/can-i-disable-full-disk-encryption)

> If Ubuntu asks for an encryption passphrase during boot (i.e. on the
>   text console before the login screen is displayed), this indicates
>   that a full disk encryption method was used. (There's more than one
>   way to do this, but I'll keep the answer general.) The encryption is
>   handled by an extra software layer between the file system and the
>   physical hard drive, not the file system itself.
>
> There is no simple method or tool to undo this. With some knowledge
>   about how Linux systems work, it can be done. You'd have to move the
>   whole file system (or all files) to another partition (with enough
>   free space) or external HDD. Then, remove the encrypted container, and
>   recreate the file system without encryption. Finally, make sure that
>   the new file system is properly recognized by the boot loader and
>   mount -a before rebooting.
>
> If possible, it's best to avoid this time consuming and error-prone
>   procedure. Just do a fresh install. For a new users, this is the
>   quickest and safest option.
>
> PS: Chances are that you can change the encryption passphrase,
>   possibly to an empty string. Then decrypting only requires to press
>   Enter. Maybe you can go further and supress to (now useless)
>   passphrase prompt. However, this does not disable the encryption. The
>   data would still be encrypted although the encryption would be useless
>   since the key can be trivially guessed.