# Auto-decrypt disk on startup? (retrieving password remotely?)

Tags: boot, encryption, disk, autostart, decryption

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and chose to do full disk encryption as well as home dir encryption.

At startup, I'm asked `Please unlock disk sda3_crypt` and I have to manually enter the disk decryption password.

I there a way to auto-mount this, i.e. by specifying the password in the boot script somewhere? (not sure about the right terminology for this)
I understand this would nullify any security.

Also, is it possible to retrieve the password from a remote URL, and use that to unlock the disk and continue booting automatically?

Note that I **don't** want to fully disable disk encryption. I wish to keep the option to re-enable it in the future. Furthermore the retrieve password remotely option (if that's possible) would allow for other possibilities, such as enabling/disabling it remotely, or preventing someone can steal the disk or machine and access it from somewhere else.

Comment: The linked question above contains [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/484023/367990) suggesting exactly what you seem to want, running a tiny script that contains the plain text password and supplies it at boot automatically. Security-wise it's like disabling the encryption completely, but it saves you the time to reinstall or migrate your system to an unencrypted drive.

Comment: @user535733 No, I wish to keep the possibility to re-enable full disk encryption in the future. Also, if I can somehow modify the script to retrieve the password from a remote URL (instead of including the password explicitly) I can essentially enable or disable the auto-decryption remotely. Or I could even make this remote URL work only for my fixed IP, so if the machine or disk gets stolen, someone can't access the data.

Comment: Well I thought that's why I'd explicitly ask to "auto decrypt on startup" and not just "disable". But I've added an extra alinea about this.

Comment: @ByteCommander Thanks, that looked promising. However I tried the approach from the comments that was specifically for 16.04.3 (which I also have) and upon rebooting I now get some kind of kernel panic error dump, and it stops completely (no interaction or option to do anything). Also tried booting in recovery mode, same. Did I just destroy my installation?

Comment: What exactly did you do? Please give as much information as possible, like a screenshot from the kernel panic and what files you edited and their current content etc. Either [edit] your current question to include everything and describe the new situation, or even better, post a new follow-up question with a link back to this here. I can then have a look if you notify me with another comment.

Comment: @ByteCommander Have posted the new issue as a [new  question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979991/ubuntu-16-04-3-kernel-panic-during-boot-after-trying-to-auto-decrypt-disk-on-st), thanks in advance if you have any insights