# Ubuntu 16.04.3 Kernel panic during boot (after trying to auto decrypt disk on startup)

Tags: boot, kernel, encryption, luks, recovery-mode

Followup to an earlier question on [having my encrypted disk auto-decrypt on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979828/auto-decrypt-disk-on-startup-retrieving-password-remotely). It seems I completely shut myself out of my system, I'm getting a kernel panic on startup.

Here's what I did:

First I added a trivial password `abc123` to unlock my partition using

```
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda3
```

Then I followed [exactly these steps](http://atterer.org/linux-remove-disable-luks-encryption-password-on-disk-partition-crypttab-initrd#comment-4024) ("How I did it on Ubuntu 16.04.3"). Note that I inserted `sudo` where appropriate.

That is:

1. appended `,keyscript=/root/lukspw` at the end of the line in `etc/crypttab` that contains `sda3_crypt (.....) none luks` (sda3 is the disk for which I was prompted during startup to enter the decryption password)
2. Created the file `/root/lukspw` with the content:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   printf "abc123"
   ```

   and made it executable: `sudo chmod +x /root/lukspw`
3. And finally:

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u -k`uname -r`
   ```

I did not get any errors during any step of the process.

Now upon reboot, either in normal or 'recovery' mode (through the Advanced option at startup) I get this:

[image: error]

And I can't do anything, no interaction, no response on keyboard activity.

Have I done something terrible? Is there still a way out of this?

Comment: Can you boot using an older kernel version from GRUB's Advanced options? The `sudo update-initramfs -u -k\`uname -r\`` should only have modified the latest kernel you were running, older kernels should still boot into the normal password prompt.

Comment: No, there is only this one (4.4.0.87), and the same in recovery mode.

Comment: Can you boot from a [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) disk and share its diagnostic output with us? I'm not sure this will contain anything useful due to the encryption, but I don't really have a clue what else to try at the moment, I'm afraid.