# Encrypting Linux server for remote access VM

Tags: 16.04, encryption, luks, cryptsetup, veracrypt

**Use Case**

I have an Ubuntu server machine wrapped in a VM (vmdk file) that contains web application.
I want to send this VM to someone and **prevent him from accessing to the internal file system of the VM** - I don't want to let him extract the machine's file system from the vmdk file.

The user can just start the machine or power it off (when the machine starts - it loads the application back-end services automatically).

**Solutions?**

I though about using a hard drive encryption (Full Disk Encryption using LUKS or other solutions like VeraCrypt) but my main concern is how it will be used in a server-based environment.

I don't want to let the user to enter any decryption keys or something like that - I saw that there are solutions for decrypting the file system automatically at start like [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/979828/auto-decrypt-disk-on-startup-retrieving-password-remotely?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59487/how-to-configure-lvm-luks-to-autodecrypt-partition) and it seems like i need to store the decryption keys inside the vm.

Is there a way to decrypt the machine by maybe using a remote user login? 
(I'm less concerned from more complex issues like side channel attacks or Hot VM Cloning). Or any other solution that can meet the use case?

**Update**

After @vidarlo answer I decided to go with the FDE solution understanding the trade-off.

Below the configuration instructions I used (Assume that the /boot resides on the /dev/sda1 unencrypted partition
and the encrypted one is on the /dev/sdaX partition).

Create a new random password and store it in the luks key store:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/boot/keyfile bs=1024 count=4
sudo chmod 0400 /boot/keyfile
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sdaX /boot/keyfile
```

Get the UUID of the /dev/sda1 partition by running:

```
sudo ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
```

Update the `/etc/crypttab` file with this content:

```
sdaX_crypt UUID=<UUID_OF_SDAX> /dev/disk/by-uuid/<UUID_OF_SDA1>:/keyfile luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/passdev
```

Update the initramfs

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a solution with unencrypted `/boot`, and a LUKS key file:

```
sudo cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sdx1 /boot/random_data_keyfile1
```

Modify `/etc/crypttab` to suit:

```
sda5_crypt UUID=DEVICE_UUID /dev/disk/by-uuid/devicewithkey:/random_data_keyfile1 luks,keyscript=/lib/cryptsetup/scripts/passdev
```

This is not foolproof. Any remotely skilled attacker will find the unencrypted `/boot`, and the keyfile. You can obscure it to make it harder, but ultimately your problem is **unsolvable**.

You want the person to be able to execute the virtual machine, yet unable to access it. Execution **requires** access. Worst case? Pause the VM, and examine memory of the VM. Anyone that has control over the hypervisor has total control over the VM, almost no matter what you do.