# When booting Ubuntu 17.10, I'm being asked for an encryption pass key

Tags: 17.10, cryptsetup

When my system is booting, I get the following before reaching the log-in screen and don't know why this is happening:
[image]
Can someone explain what's happening? I find it cumbersome to enter my encryption passkey and password while booting.

Comment: Yes. I am trying to remove it. In fact. I tried installing ubuntu again from boot menu. The problem persists in the new installation too.

Comment: Your  original question has been answered.  If you would like to remove the encryption, you should have [a look here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245112/can-i-disable-full-disk-encryption)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is easy:  your disk is encrypted and *cannot be read by Ubuntu* and needs your decryption key so the encryption layer can then decrypt the disk so it can be read.

**The advantage:** If your computer gets stolen *no one* including the NSA, CIA, KGB, ... can read your disk.

**The disadvantage:** well... you have to type the encryption key when the system boots.

Comment: Will I have performance issues due to encryption?

Comment: @JeethJoseph Other than a little bit more time for booting, the performance issues are absolutely negligible.

Comment: .....including the NSA, CIA, KGB. That claim is a bit bold, I would not bet on it.

Comment: Haha. Don't really have anything for the CIA on my laptop. :D

Comment: @Bruni OpenSource is still the best bet for encryption.  :-)