# Dual Boot: Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 - Bitlocker Asking for a key

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10, bootloader, grub-efi

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10. Ubuntu has been working pretty good for the most part, Windows 10, on the other hand, is not too happy. I tried to go into Windows 10 from Grub, and the BitLocker screen comes up asking for a key that I do not have.

I have tried several things. Including trying to disable BitLocker from the command line [As I seen from other posts], but it tells me it is encrypted and it cannot perform the operation. I tried starting in safe mode, and I have tried booting from my "Windows 10 Recovery USB" that I made prior to the install, but again it won't let me choose that partition because it is encrypted.

I backed up my data in case something crazy happened so at this point I would be willing to wipe the drive clean and install a fresh install of Windows.

Any ideas or recommendations?

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. Can you boot Windows directly from your UEFI boot menu?

Answer (score 1):

You probably activated Full Disk Encryption when installing Ubuntu 18.04, and doing this encrypted the Windows partition too. I don't think it's impossible to remove the LUKS encryption, but it's not easy at all for a beginner (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/245159/761978) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60971/how-to-remove-luks-encryption/60973#60973)). If you have all your data backed up, just do a fresh install of both Windows and Ubuntu. And don't activate LUKS again, try some other encryption technique if it's important for you to have encryption, [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029249/how-to-encrypt-home-on-ubuntu-18-04) may be a good starting point.