# Trouble booting after moving Ubuntu 18.04 across drives

Tags: boot, virtualbox

**Background**

I'm on VirtualBox 6.0.12. I had a drive which contained a `/boot` partition, and an encrypted (LUKS) main partition. I wished to remove the encryption and apparently the best way to do this was to migrate Ubuntu to a new drive.

**Prior Actions**

I used this answer to move the partition contents. I moved both `/boot` and the main `/` partition contents. As far as I can tell, it moved it just fine.

https://askubuntu.com/a/741727/128596

As part of step 5 of the above answer, I used the steps below through used of a live CD (no errors reported).

https://askubuntu.com/a/88432/128596

After doing this it seems to boot the Ubuntu partition okay, but got stuck at the (basic looking) Ubuntu 4 dot loading screen ([like this one but with 18.04 text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuQVY.png)).

When I got stuck there, I looked to other answers and I tried to [run boot-repair from the live CD](https://askubuntu.com/a/182863/128596) but I just got back to the 4 dot loading screen.

**Later Events**

If I wait for long enough I get dropped to an initramfs screen, and upon trying to `exit` it I get this behaviour.

Playing around with enabling/disabling 3D acceleration and changing VirtualBox graphics driver don't seem to work.

[image: initramfs screen]

**Question**

What actions, if any, can I take to fix this?

Comment: Boot the source system to unencrypt all partitions then use this script to clone to a new unencrypted partition: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-backkup-clone-ubuntu-to-another-partition/1028605#1028605

Comment: The problem is that there is apparently no easy way to decrypt the partition. https://askubuntu.com/a/245159/128596 That's why I did the migration to begin with.

Comment: The script migrates using `rsync` how did you migrate?

Comment: I used `cp -a` in conjunction with the other steps mentioned here https://askubuntu.com/a/741727/128596

Comment: I have not tried that to clone a partition but maybe `sudo` in front?