# How to remove disk sda3_crypt password from ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: password, disk

I somehow activated disk sda3_crypt password long back which shows at the very beginning other than the administrator password and now, I'm not being able to remove it. Any help ?

Comment: Do you know the `sdax_crypt` password or you forgot it? And is your `/home` and `/root` seperate and which one is encrypted? In any case you need to move the whole file system  to another partition. Then, remove the encrypted container, recreate the file system without encryption and recreate the `/boot` pointing it to the new partition.

Comment: I know the sdax_crypt password, and I just want to remove it, the whole password thing so that I don't have to enter it again. And no, I don't want to move any file to another partition, just want to remove this password.

Comment: Hi, I basically gave an overview of the process but there is **no** in place method of decrypting a LUKS volume due to the security issues it might pose. I suggest you go through [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Removing_system_encryption) or [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245112/) but the process is rather error prone and a reinstall/keeping the encryption as it is would be much easier.