# How can I decrypt my ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04

I installed Ubuntu, and during the installation I enabled the option to encrypt the disk, now I can't boot to install another OS. How can I decrypt the disk?

(I'm a very beginner, I'm still studying, help me pls !!!)

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want to share disk between two OSes, and have one or both of them encrypted, you must pre-prepare the partitions and install only to a single partition. Depending on release this is more work as the *modern* method of encryption is *full disk encryption* thus setting it up is a more manual task unless your box has two drives and you are installing one OS to each drive (thus both can be encrypted/unencrypted or combination using more automated install options). You gave no specifics on this though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I disable full-disk encryption?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/245112/can-i-disable-full-disk-encryption)

Answer (score 1):

When you try to mount the volume you should be prompted for a password.

You need to enter the correct password that you set up when you initially set up the encryption.

If you don't remember the password, you will not be able to decrypt the volume. That's the whole point of encryption!  If you do not know the correct authentication, you will need to delete the partition or format the disk to be able to use it again.

Comment: hello Nmath
the password I remember, I would like to disable this option, is it possible?

Comment: See: [Can I disable full-disk encryption?](https://askubuntu.com/q/245112).  The short answer is "No"-- you would need to reinstall the OS without using full disk encryption.

Answer (score 1):

"Booting" to install another OS, however, should not be related to an Ubuntu installation that is encrypted. Instead, that involves going to BIOS and have the computer boot from a bootable install medium. That works independent of an encrypted installation. So you may need to provide more detail on what is not working here.

You cannot convert an existing encrypted installation to an unencrypted one. Your only option to achieve an unencrypted installation is to reinstall new, wiping the existing installation (make sure your backup of your own user data is up to date, because all data on the existing installation will be wiped).

Comment: even changing the boot order, it doesn’t reach the installation part of the new system ... it goes straight to the screen that asks for the ubuntu encryption password and starts the operating system again

Comment: You have to change the boot order to a live install USB or DVD. That one must effectively be bootable, i.e., properly made, for this to work. If you point the system to a drive that cannot boot, it will fall back to the other entries, i.e., your current install.